# Distance between the boundaries of a convex set and its shrunk version

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $S$ be a compact convex set and $S'=\{x\in S: d(x, \partial S)\ge \delta\}$, where $d$ is the Euclidean distance and $\partial S$ is the boundary of $S$. Assume that we choose $\delta>0$ such that $S'$ is non-empty. I was wondering how $$\sup_{x\in S}\inf_{y\in S'}d(x,y)$$
is related to $\delta$. I guess the curvature may be involved here.

Comment: If $x \in S$ and $x' \in S'_\delta$, then $d(x, y) \ge \delta$. So your $\sup \inf$ is $\ge \delta$.

Comment: @dohmatob: If $S=\bar{B}(0,r)$ then $S'=\bar{B}(0,r-\delta)$ and $d(0,0) = 0 < \delta$.

Comment: @dohmatob: However, if $S$ is proper, if $s' \in S'$ you can always find some sequence $s_k \in S$ such that $\limsup_k d(s',s_k) \ge \delta$. So all you need is $S$ to be proper and $S'$ non empty.

Comment: Sure. I misread $S'$ as $\{x \in X |d(x, S)\ge \delta\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=\sup_{x\in S}\inf_{y\in S'} \|x-y\|$. Since $S$ is compact and $d$ is continuous, we
see that $S'$ is closed and hence compact. Hence $m=\max_{x\in S}\min_{y\in S'} \|x-y\|$.

Note that $m \ge \delta$. Choose $x \in S, y \in S'$ such that $\|x-y\| = m$. Note that
$[s',s] \subset S$ and then $s \in \partial S$ (otherwise there is
some $t>1$ such that $s'+t(s-s') \in S$, and then $\|x-y\| - s'\| = t \|x-y\| > m$). Since
$\|x-y\| \ge \delta$ we have $m \ge \delta$.

Note that $m$ can be strictly larger than $\delta$. Take the $S$ to be the subset of the plane given by the convex hull of $\overline{B}(0,\delta) $ and the point $(p,0)$. Then $S'=\{0\}$ and 
$m = |p|$.